# C++ UDP server for a game

Tags: c++, c++11, server, callback, boost

I broke my server into two classes, a general server class and a client session class.

I know the code isn't documented in the header, but I am more interested in the design of the server/session model and whether or not responsibility is correctly broken up between the modules. Also, whether or not the callbacks for sending and receiving data are implemented in a good style.

`server.hpp`

```
class LaserTagServer {
public:
    LaserTagServer(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, short port); 

private:
    void Receive();
    void onReceive(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred, std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint> client_endpoint,
            std::shared_ptr<Protocol::ClientDataHeader> header, std::shared_ptr<Protocol::TransmittedData> data); 
    void NewSession(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint &endpoint);
    void Laser(LaserTagClientSession &firing_session);
    void Send(const boost::system::error_code &error);
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Protocol::TransmittedData>> GameState();
    std::shared_ptr<Protocol::ServerDataHeader> HeaderForClient(int client_num);
    void OnSend(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred, 
            std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Protocol::TransmittedData>> game_state, std::shared_ptr<Protocol::ServerDataHeader> header);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
    std::map<int, LaserTagClientSession> client_sessions_;
    int red_team_count_, blue_team_count_, player_count_;
    int red_score_, blue_score_;
    int server_seq_num_;
};
```

`server.cpp`

```
    LaserTagServer::LaserTagServer(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, short port) 
        : socket_(io_service, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), port)), 
          timer_(io_service) {
    // Initialize variables
    player_count_ = red_team_count_ = blue_team_count_ = red_score_ = blue_score_ = 0;
    server_seq_num_ = 0;

    // Begin sending game state to clients
    timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&LaserTagServer::Send, this, _1));

    // Begin receving data from clients
    Receive();
    }

void LaserTagServer::Receive() {
    // Initialize buffer
    std::shared_ptr<ClientDataHeader> header(new ClientDataHeader());
    std::shared_ptr<TransmittedData> data(new TransmittedData());
    boost::array<boost::asio::mutable_buffer, 2> buffer = {boost::asio::buffer(header.get(), sizeof(ClientDataHeader)), boost::asio::buffer(data.get(), sizeof(TransmittedData))};

    // Perform asynchronous read call
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint> client_endpoint(new boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint());
    socket_.async_receive_from(buffer, *client_endpoint, 
        boost::bind(&LaserTagServer::onReceive, this, _1, _2, client_endpoint, header, data));
}

void LaserTagServer::onReceive(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred, std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint> client_endpoint,
        std::shared_ptr<ClientDataHeader> header, std::shared_ptr<TransmittedData> data) { 
    // Process client data from async receive
    if (!error) {
        if (header->request) {
            NewSession(*client_endpoint);
        } else {
            // Fetch client
            LaserTagClientSession &update_session = client_sessions_.find(data->player_num)->second; // TODO if session doesn't exist will crash

            // If we successfully update their data (i.e. data is valid and recent) and they are shooting, check for collisions
            update_session.UpdateClientState(header->seq_num, *data); 

            // If client is firing laser, do that
            if(update_session.GetPlayer().Laser()) {
                Laser(update_session);
            }
        }
    }

    // Receive next client data
    Receive();
}

void LaserTagServer::NewSession(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint &endpoint) {
    // Add new client to game
    Team team = red_team_count_ > blue_team_count_ ? blue : red;
    TransmittedData new_data;
    new_data.player_num = player_count_;
    new_data.team = team;
    new_data.laser = false;
    LaserTagClientSession new_session(endpoint, new_data);
    client_sessions_.insert(std::pair<int, LaserTagClientSession>(player_count_, new_session));

    std::cout << "Added client session " << player_count_ << " at " << new_session.GetEndpoint().address() << std::endl;

    // Update counters
    player_count_++;
    if (team == blue) { 
        blue_team_count_++;
    } else { 
        red_team_count_++;
    }
}

void LaserTagServer::Laser(LaserTagClientSession &firing_session) {
    // Get firing player
    const Player &firing = firing_session.GetPlayer();

    // Iterate through the opponents
    for (auto iter = client_sessions_.begin(); iter != client_sessions_.end(); iter++) {
        // Extract the session and player from key value pair
        LaserTagClientSession &opponent_session = iter->second;
        const Player &opponent = opponent_session.GetPlayer();

        // If this player is an opponent
        if (opponent.Team() != firing.Team()) {
            // If the laser intersects with the opponent
            if (VectorIntersectsConvexPolygon(opponent.Vertices(), firing.Position(), firing.Direction())) {
                // Spawn the opponent
                opponent_session.Spawn();

                // Update the score
                if (firing.Team() == blue) 
                    blue_score_++; 
                else 
                    red_score_++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void LaserTagServer::Send(const boost::system::error_code &error) {
    // Get state of game
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<TransmittedData>> game_state = GameState();

    // Send state of game to all clients
    for (auto iter = client_sessions_.begin(); iter != client_sessions_.end(); iter++) {
        // Create header for specific client
        std::shared_ptr<ServerDataHeader> header(new ServerDataHeader());
        header->client_player_num = iter->first;
        header->num_players = client_sessions_.size();
        header->red_score = red_score_;
        header->blue_score = blue_score_;
        header->server_seq_num = server_seq_num_;

        // Buffer and write aysnc
        boost::array<boost::asio::const_buffer, 2> buffer = {boost::asio::buffer(header.get(), sizeof(ServerDataHeader)), boost::asio::buffer(*game_state)};
        socket_.async_send_to(buffer, iter->second.GetEndpoint(), boost::bind(&LaserTagServer::OnSend, this, _1, _2, game_state, header));
    }

    // Update server sequence number
    server_seq_num_++;

    // Schedule event to send game state to all clients
    timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&LaserTagServer::Send, this, _1));
}

std::shared_ptr<ServerDataHeader> LaserTagServer::HeaderForClient(int client_num) {
// Create header for specific client
std::shared_ptr<ServerDataHeader> header(new ServerDataHeader());
header->client_player_num = client_num;
header->num_players = client_sessions_.size();
header->red_score = red_score_;
header->blue_score = blue_score_;
header->server_seq_num = server_seq_num_;

return header;
}

std::shared_ptr<std::vector<TransmittedData>> LaserTagServer::GameState() {
    // Buffer state of game
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<TransmittedData>> game_state(new std::vector<TransmittedData>());

    // Iterate over the client sessions
    for (auto iter = client_sessions_.begin(); iter != client_sessions_.end(); /* Not while deleting */) {
        if (iter->second.SessionExpired()) {
            // If client session has expired, remove them from the game
            std::cout << "Client " << iter->first << " session ended" << std::endl;
            if (iter->second.ClientState().team == blue) 
                blue_team_count_--; 
            else 
                red_team_count_--;
            client_sessions_.erase(iter++);
        } else {
            // Add the client state to the vector
            game_state->push_back((iter++)->second.ClientState());         
        }
    }

    return game_state;
}

void LaserTagServer::OnSend(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred, 
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<TransmittedData>> game_state, std::shared_ptr<ServerDataHeader> header) {
    // Method maintains ownership of buffer data until async send has completed
}
```

And here is the client session class

`session.hpp`

```
class LaserTagClientSession {
    public:
        LaserTagClientSession(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint client_endpoint, Protocol::TransmittedData &data); 

        Protocol::TransmittedData ClientState();

        const Player &GetPlayer();

        void UpdateClientState(int new_seq_num, Protocol::TransmittedData &data);

        const boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint &GetEndpoint();

        bool SessionExpired();

        void Spawn();

    private:
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint_;
        boost::posix_time::ptime last_received_;
        unsigned int seq_num_;
        boost::mt19937 random_num_gen_; 
        Player player_;
};
```

`session.cpp`

```
LaserTagClientSession::LaserTagClientSession(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint client_endpoint, TransmittedData &data) 
    : endpoint_(client_endpoint), 
      last_received_(boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time()),
      player_(data),
      seq_num_(0) {
    // Random number generator
    boost::posix_time::ptime time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    boost::posix_time::time_duration duration(time.time_of_day());
    random_num_gen_ = boost::mt19937(duration.total_milliseconds());

    // Spawn coordinates and direction
    Spawn();
}

TransmittedData LaserTagClientSession::ClientState() {
    return player_.Data();
}

const Player &LaserTagClientSession::GetPlayer() {
    return player_;
}

void LaserTagClientSession::UpdateClientState(int new_seq_num, TransmittedData &data) {
    if (new_seq_num < seq_num_) {
        // Check sequence number
        return;
    } else if (Norm(player_.Position() - Vector2D(data.x_pos, data.y_pos)) > 25) {
        // Check client didn't try to move too far
        return;
    } else {
        // Update
        last_received_ = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
        seq_num_ = new_seq_num;
        player_.Update(data);
    }
}

const boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint &LaserTagClientSession::GetEndpoint() {
    return endpoint_;
}

bool LaserTagClientSession::SessionExpired() {
    boost::posix_time::time_duration duration = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time() - last_received_;
    return duration.seconds() > 2;
}

void LaserTagClientSession::Spawn() {
    // Random coordinates in game 
    boost::uniform_real<> coord_distr(-250, 250);
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937 &, boost::uniform_real<>> coord_random(random_num_gen_, coord_distr);
    player_.SetPosition(Vector2D(coord_random(), coord_random()));

    // Random direction
    boost::uniform_int<> dir_distr(0, 71); // 5 degree turns (72 between 0 and 360)
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937 &, boost::uniform_int<>> dir_random(random_num_gen_, dir_distr);
    player_.SetDirection(RotateDegrees(Vector2D(1, 0), dir_random()));
}
```

Comment: The code is here if anyone is interested https://github.com/shanecarey17/LaserTag